# DRY way to call method if object does not exist, or flag set?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django database containing Paper objects, and a management command to populate the database. The management command iterates over a list of IDs and scrapes information about each one, and uses this information to populate the database.

This command is run each week, and any new IDs are added to the database. If the object already exists, I don't scrape, which speeds things up hugely:

```
try:
    paper = Paper.objects.get(id=id)
except Paper.DoesNotExist:
    info = self._scrape_info(id)
    self._create_or_update_item(info, id)
```

Now I want to set an `UPDATE_ALL` flag on the management command to update information about existing Paper objects, as well as just creating new ones. The problem is that it's not very DRY:

```
try:
    paper = Paper.objects.get(id=id)
    if UPDATE_ALL:
        info = self._scrape_info(id)
        self._create_or_update_item(info, id)
except Paper.DoesNotExist:
    info = self._scrape_info(id)
    self._create_or_update_item(info, id)
```

How can I make this DRYer?

Django obviously has the `get_or_create` method, which I'm using in `_create_or_update_item`. However, I only want to call `self._scrape_info`, as well as creating or updating the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like

```
obj, created = Paper.objects.update_or_create(
    name='Paper')
```

There is a `update_or_create` in Django since 1.7. 
Take a look into [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) if that is suitable for you.

> A convenience method for updating an object with the given kwargs,
>   creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of
>   (field, value) pairs used to update the object. The values in defaults
>   can be callables.

Comment: Thanks - it's not really relevant. My logic is 'run scrape if (a) paper doesn't exist OR (b) flag set' - I'd like to combine that into a single line. It's not really so much about what I do with the paper itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could incapsulate the parsing process into a helper method:

```
def scrape_new_object(self, id, force_update=False):
    if not force_update:
        try:
            Paper.objects.get(id=id)
            return
        except Paper.DoesNotExists:
            pass

    info = self._scrape_info(id)
    self._create_or_update_item(info, id)
```

and then passing `UPDATE_ALL` as value to `force_update`

```
MyCommand.scrape_new_object(id, force_update=UPDATE_ALL)
```